# error when building the arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, toolchain, binutils, eabi

**FOREWORD** : My build system is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server edition

I have bumped into a common issue while cross-compiling binutils for the **arm-none-eabi** toolchain.

After downloading the sources from :

https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.8/4.8-2014-q3-update/+download/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805-src.tar.bz2

I extracted the tarball and patched zlib with :

```
$ cd ./gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src
$ find -name '*.tar.*' | xargs -I% tar -xf %
$ cd zlib-1.2.5
$ patch -p1 <../zlib-1.2.5.patch
$ cd ../../
```

according to the instructions of the bundled PDF guide. I then applied this `sed` patch :

```
sed -i -e 's/@colophon/@@colophon/' -e 's/doc@cygnus.com/doc@@cygnus.com/' bfd/doc/bfd.texinfo
```

and launched the `./build-prerequisites.sh --skip_mingw32` and `./build-toolchain.sh --skip_mingw32` scripts.

Altough the `./build-prerequisites.sh --skip_mingw32` works fine, the toolchain script ends with an error in the binutils install procedure :

```
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4416: warning: @itemx should not begin @table
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4424: @itemx must follow @item
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4428: @itemx must follow @item
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4434: @itemx must follow @item
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4438: @itemx must follow @item
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4448: @itemx must follow @item
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:2404: warning: node next `ranlib' in menu `readelf' and in sectioning `size' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:2482: warning: node prev `size' in menu `readelf' and in sectioning `ranlib' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:2706: warning: node next `strip' in menu `elfedit' and in sectioning `c++filt' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3259: warning: node next `nlmconv' in menu `windres' and in sectioning `windmc' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3364: warning: node next `windmc' in menu `dlltool' and in sectioning `windres' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3364: warning: node prev `windmc' in menu `windres' and in sectioning `nlmconv' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3525: warning: node next `windres' in menu `windmc' and in sectioning `dlltool' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3525: warning: node prev `windres' in menu `nlmconv' and in sectioning `windmc' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3719: warning: node next `dlltool' in menu `Common Options' and in sectioning `readelf' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:3719: warning: node prev `dlltool' in menu `windmc' and in sectioning `windres' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4122: warning: node next `readelf' in menu `size' and in sectioning `elfedit' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4122: warning: node prev `readelf' in menu `ranlib' and in sectioning `dlltool' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4376: warning: node next `elfedit' in menu `c++filt' and in sectioning `Common Options' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4376: warning: node prev `elfedit' in menu `strip' and in sectioning `readelf' differ
/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/src/binutils/binutils/doc/binutils.texi:4470: warning: node prev `Common Options' in menu `dlltool' and in sectioning `elfedit' differ
make[3]: *** [binutils.html] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils/doc'
Making html in po
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils/po'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `html'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils/po'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `html-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils'
make[2]: *** [html-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils/binutils'
make[1]: *** [html-binutils] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/arturo/ARM_CROSS/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805/build-native/binutils'
make: *** [do-install-html] Error 2
```

I have also edited the second script by replacing the `make` calls with the `make MAKEFINFO=true` ones but I get this error...

....any suggestions about it ? I have been googling around so far and found that these ones are common problems occuring when working with the Ubuntu distros, but I still can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance, Arturo

Comment: Take a look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and let it make such a work for you.

Comment: I believe buildroot will make Linux hosted compilers.  Crosstool-ng has scripts, but will not build this particular compiler variant by default.  I would suggest you just not build the documentation as it is available from several different places?